# Unable to share a view on table in SNOWFLAKE database to Native App application

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm unable to share a view that gets data from table in SNOWFLAKE database to Native App.

As suggested [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/requesting-privs#label-native-apps-privs-supported:%7E:text=To%20grant%20the%20IMPORT%20privilege%20on%20the%20SNOWFLAKE%20database%2C%20run%20the%20following%20command%3A) I'm adding GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES on this database first.

I first run all these commands in SQL to add view to my app package and allow permissions on that view:

```
 --CREATE VIEW IN APP PACKAGE TO ACCESS SNOWFLAKE DB
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE SNOWFLAKE TO APPLICATION RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_APP;
USE RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_PACKAGE.SHARED_DATA;
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_PACKAGE.SHARED_DATA.CREDITS_USED_ALL_TIME_VIEW
AS
SELECT WAREHOUSE_NAME
      ,SUM(CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE) AS CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE_SUM
  FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA SHARED_DATA TO SHARE IN APPLICATION PACKAGE RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_PACKAGE;
GRANT SELECT ON VIEW RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_PACKAGE.SHARED_DATA.CREDITS_USED_ALL_TIME_VIEW TO SHARE IN APPLICATION PACKAGE RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_PACKAGE;
```

all executes ok except last command that gives:

**Failure during expansion of view 'CREDITS_USED_ALL_TIME_VIEW': SQL compilation error: A view being added to the shared content cannot reference objects inside another application or application package.**
My view is not referencing "objects inside another application or application package" but in SNOWFLAKE database.

GRANT IMPORTED statement is executed ok.

View is also created ok within app package - I can see it and run it ok from SQL.

I just don't know how to allow app to use it.

I also tried to run:

```
GRANT REFERENCE_USAGE ON DATABASE SNOWFLAKE TO SHARE IN APPLICATION PACKAGE RESOURCE_OPTIMIZATION_USAGE_MONITORING_PACKAGE;
```

as suggested [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/preparing-data-content#:%7E:text=Before%20sharing%20an,PACKAGE%20app_pkg%3B) because is seems logical to do that first actually but got:

```
Granting individual privileges on imported database is not allowed. Use 'GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES' instead.
```

Which I already did tried and failed.

Answer (score 0):

Re-sharing of data is not allowed. Consumer account can't reshare data to other accounts.

Snowflake database is shared to your Snowflake account and you can't reshare this database data to other accounts.

This is explained at https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-can-we-share-data-from-account-usage-schema-from-one-account-to-other-accounts-in-the-same-organization

Comment: I'm not trying to share my Snowflake DB with other accounts. I'm trying to build app that will enable deeper view in his own Snowflake DB...which is possible: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/requesting-privs#label-native-apps-privs-supported:%7E:text=To%20grant%20the%20IMPORT%20privilege%20on%20the%20SNOWFLAKE%20database%2C%20run%20the%20following%20command%3A:~:text=APPLICATION%20hello_snowflake_app%3B-,Granting%20Privileges%20to%20an%20Application,-%C2%B6